# Polarion Web services API - How to create a project?

Tags: api, soap, wsdl, polarion

Looking at the list of available polarion webservices wsdl api functions,  I don't see one for creating a polarion project.  I have had no luck in finding out how I can create a polarion project via scripting to the polarion soap (wsdl) API.

Answer (score 1):

**It is not possible.**

I was looking through the (in my opinion) three relevant classes when it comes to using the API and I could not find a createProject method.

The three relevant classes are:

http://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/sdk/doc/javadoc/com/polarion/alm/ws/client/projects/ProjectWebService.html

http://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/sdk/doc/javadoc/com/polarion/alm/ws/client/session/SessionWebService.html

http://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/sdk/doc/javadoc/com/polarion/alm/ws/client/tracker/TrackerWebService.html

There is a createProject method however in the following interface
but importing that did also not work. It is not part of ws/client so I think the method is only ment to be implemented in Polarion Wikipages with Velocity Code.
http://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/sdk/doc/javadoc/com/polarion/alm/projects/IProjectLifecycleManager.html