# Polarion Web services API - How to create a user?

Tags: soap-client, polarion

Looking at the list of available polarion webservices wsdl api functions, I don't see one for creating a polarion user. I have had no luck in finding out how I can create a polarion user via scripting to the polarion soap (wsdl) API. preferably in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it but Polarions Java doc says it is possible with the ProjectWebservices class:
http://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/sdk/doc/javadoc/com/polarion/alm/ws/client/projects/ProjectWebService.html

I actually recommend to work with Java as the API seems to be catered to this. I have not tested however if it is even possible to set up Python scripts accessing the API.

What is btw definitely NOT possible is creating projects via the API, see my answer here:
[Polarion Web services API - How to create a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388833/polarion-web-services-api-how-to-create-a-project)